# ZXing QR code size

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

The [QRCodeWriter.encode](http://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeWriter.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat,%20int,%20int)) method provides a `width` and `height` parameter that are the *preferred* size in pixels.  I have one URL, when encoded, produces a QR Code sized precisely to the dimensions passed in.  However, a different URL, albeit somewhat longer, produces a QR code that is 12% larger than the dimensions specified.  Is there a way to force the QR code to fit within a certain size limit?

Answer (score 0):

QR codes are just encoding (with error correction), which means that, as the input grows, the output has to grow proportionately.

If you want your QRs of the same size then you must limit the input, maybe using [tinyurl](http://tinyurl.com/)?

Comment: That makes sense-- similar to a bar code. However, I would think the pitch of the individual squares should increase to fit within the desired size.